# Device_map not wokring for ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM - Potential bug?

Tags: huggingface, onnx, tensorrt, onnxruntime

Reposted from here: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/device-map-not-wokring-for-ortmodelforseq2seqlm-potential-bug/78982

I have a non-KV Cache T5 Onnx Model that I'm trying to load using `huggingface`/ `optimum.onnxruntime`. There are two issues

### with `CUDAExecutionProvider`

```
model = ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name, provider="CUDAExecutionProvider", task="text2text-generation", use_cache=False, use_io_binding=False, device_map="cuda:3")
```

The same thing happens with a model that has `with_past`:

```
model_kv = ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name, provider="CUDAExecutionProvider", task="text2text-generation-with-past", use_cache=True, use_io_binding=True, device_map="cuda:3")
```

Both load loads fine, except that both ignores `device_map` and loads it to `cuda:0`, which means I can't load multiple models two models for testing or serving since my model is relatively large and can only fit one on a gpu.

### with `TensorrtExecutionProvider`

Then I tried `TensorrtExecutionProvider` (on non KV cache model). The model thinks that its loaded into the wrong cuda, but it's actually on CPU. Because the model in reality is on CPU, its immensely slow to load.

```
model = ORTModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name, provider="TensorrtExecutionProvider", task="text2text-generation", use_cache=False, use_io_binding=False, device_map="cuda:3")
```

`model.device` shows `device(type='cuda', index=0)`. However, my `nvitop` shows that there is hardly any memory use on `cuda:0` (`3746MB` used up from my base of `872MB` - it could be that  the model graph is indeed loaded onto cuda_0 but the data isn't). If I look into my cpu main memory, I see that utilization has increased by `60GB`, the size of my model. So the model that I wanted to load into `cuda:3` thinks its on `cuda:0` but is actually on CPU.

I have this in my os environment:

```
export ONNX_MODE=cuda
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin:$PATH
export CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64:/home/zm/workspace/packages/TensorRT-8.6.1.6/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Wondering how I can fix this? What I want in both cases is to be able to put the model on what ever device (cuda0-7) that I want. I can get them there with a `.to("cuda:3")` but this essentially causes me to do a total-reload which is slow.